# How to Hide or not Load Non Editable Component in Experience Editor?

Tags: experience-editor

In a Page component like Header or Footer are not editable,Is there a way that i can hide these component in Experience Editor mode. Or do not load the component at all in Experience Editor.

Comment: yes check if IsExpEditorMode , then dont load the inner html of header/footer and display a message to author - This content is not editable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if page is opened experience editor mode.

```
@if (!Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor)
{
  <!-- Header Markup -->
}
```